# Does SQL Server Express 2016 come with SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation, tools, configuration-manager

Does SQL Server Express 2016 come with SQL Server Configuration Manager?

If not, is there any licenced way to add SQL Server Configuration Manager to an existing installation of SQL Server Express 2016?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already installed SQL Server 2016 Express Edition, you can find configuration manager here:

Computer Management > Services and Applications > SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Just seacrh for SQLServerManager13.msc from the search option in bottom left.

SQL Server 2017      C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc

SQL Server 2016      C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc

Comment: Is there any way to find the .msc files that appear in the Computer Management?